# How much to disturb a non-invertible element in $\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$ to make it invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra

For a given singular matrix in $\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$, what's the smallest number of entries one has to modify in order to make it invertible?

Comment: For the zero matrix, the answer is $n$.

Comment: For a generic singular matrix the answer is one entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to change a number of entries equal to the nullity of the matrix, which for a square matrix is the multiplicity of the eigenvalue 0.

If the matrix has rank $r$, then there are $r$ rows that can linearly combine to make the remaining $n-r$ rows. If you change one entry in one of the remaining $n-r$ rows to make it linearly independent, you now have a matrix with rank $r+1$. Repeat this argument until you have a matrix of rank $n$, which is invertible if it is $n\times n$. Thus it will take at least $n-r$ changes, which is the nullity of the matrix.

Answer (score 0):

There are *some* matrices for which the answer is 1, for example $\mathcal I_n$ where the top-left entry has been changed to a $0$ (or indeed, any of the entries on the diagonal changed to $0$).

But as user1551 said in their comment, the answer for $0_n$ (the $n \times n$ zero matrix) would be $n$.

I think $n$ would be the maximum; you could imagine starting with just the first row of the matrix and then add each row one at a time, and if the new row was linearly dependent, change one element in the new row such that it isn't any more. (Something akin to [Cantor's Diagonal Argument](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Real_Numbers_are_Uncountable#Cantor.27s_Diagonal_Argument) for the real numbers being uncountable, if you've come across that.)

Certainly, a very crude upper bound is $\frac{1}{2}n(n+1)$, which is the number of changes it would take to make it upper- or lower-diagonal with nonzero entries on the diagonal.

Comment: In fact, you can show that the upper bound is $n$ inductively: change $n-1$ elements in the upper-left $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ submatrix to make it invertible (i.e. with non-zero determinant); then the determinant of the full matrix is a linear combination of e.g. the elements on the bottom row, each multiplied by (plus/minus) the determinant of the relevant minor; since we'e ensured that the minor for our bottom-right element has non-zero determinant, we can then choose a value for the bottom-right element that makes the entire determinant non-zero.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki is the bound tight?

Comment: @user2471 The example of the zero matrix shows that there are matrices that take $n$ changes, and my comment shows that for any matrix there's some set of $n$ changes that will work. Certain matrices (for instance, the identity matrix with the top-left entry replaced by zero) have solutions that take fewer changes, but no matrix requires more.